# Is there a way to move a Label after using grid

Tags: python, tkinter

If I were to make a label using

```
from Tkinter import *
r = Tk()
l = Label(r,text = 'hi').grid(row = 0,column = 0)
```

Is there a way to move the button later using something like

```
l.config(row = 1, column = 2)
```

or something like that?

Comment: Why didn't you try it before asking?

Comment: I did try, but I couldn't figure out what I would have to do; config returned 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: You should have put that error message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid_forget` to remove the label from the window, and then re-grid it to change it's position. It won't destroy the widget that you move, but you will need a reference to the widget to keep applying `grid` and `grid_forget` to it.

Example:

```
r = Tk()
l = Label(r, text='hi')
l.grid(row=0, column=0)
l.grid_forget()
l.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

Comment: You don't need to first call `grid_forget()`. Simply calling `grid` with new paramters is all that is necessary.